# Crawling Data from stack overflow and careers 2.0

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jobs

I am thinking of making a recommendation engine that looks for job listings in careers 2.0 and activity of a user in stack overflow so as to recommend user (without a career profile) about prospective jobs he can take up.

I am aware of the crawling policies for stack overflow or the dumps that I can use. Now the question is whether the same applies for careers 2.0 or are there some additional restrictions?

My project is more or less a hobby project as part of my course in NLP. WIll it be advantageous if I use the API for stack overflow to get the user details and activities?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for browsing Careers data and no plan to make that happen.  Currently the only profiles exposed to the internet are ones available via public urls, but you'll have to find those elsewhere as we do not maintain a public list of those urls (they are intended for sharing your profile with others, not for browsing).

If you really wanted to try to get the profiles, you could buy a search subscription and pull down the data from there, however there is no contact information available for any of them.